# Start any application through termux command line for example chrome, youtube and some other application like cryptotabbrowser

Tags: android, command-line, termux

How to open any application available in phone or installed through termux command line?
I can run only chrome with this command but how to open other applications?

```
am start --user 0 -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

Answer (score 6):

1. configure your device in developer mode
2. connect the device to a PC over USB
3. install the android debugger on the PC
4. get the list of packages on the device:

```bash
$ adb shell pm list packages -f -3
```

this is easiest if you grep for what you want (example: X server):

```bash
$ adb shell pm list packages -f -3 | grep -i server
package:/data/app/x.org.server-pn6gNfAPA-hplcvZLS-JsA==/base.apk=x.org.server
```

5. find the list of activities for the package you want to work with:

```bash
$ PACKAGE=x.org.server
$ adb shell dumpsys package | grep -Eo $(printf "^[[:space:]]+[0-9a-f]+[[:space:]]+%s/[^[:space:]]+" "${PACKAGE}") | grep -oE "[^[:space:]]+$"
x.org.server/.RunFromOtherApp
x.org.server/.MainActivity
x.org.server/.MainActivity
```

6. use your `am start` command with the above found activity name:

```bash
am start --user 0 -n x.org.server/.RunFromOtherApp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that doesn't need any dependency. Note that you don't need `adb` at all: you can run `am` and `sudo dumpsys` from Termux.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the same answer for termux

```
am start --user 0 -n com.Package.name/activityclass
```

You can find activity class through `apk info` app available in Google Playstore.

Comment: apk name -->apk info

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should do it.

```
am start --user 0 -n com.Package.name/activityclass
```

To find the activity class and stuff, there is an app called [Dev Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools). You can inspect any personal app, using this app. You can also find the Activity class there, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Termux Launcher](https://github.com/amsitlab/termuxlauncher)

This app provides a command `launch [ShortAppName]` to open any app.